# Trying to use the Havok Project Anarachy to create a project, wont build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, havok

I used the vGameSolutionCreator in vForge to create a project called "Test1", when i open it in Visual Studio 2012 (or Visual Studio 2010 for that matter) and build it, i get the error

```
Error   1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libgfx.lib'    C:\Users\dev1\Documents\AnarchyProjects\Test1\Source\Test1Plugin\LINK   Test1Plugin100 (Visual Studio 2010)
```

Does anyone know what im missing and/or a solution to this problem?

Comment: See http://forum.projectanarchy.com/showthread.php?900-Linker-Problem-building-plugin-LNK1104-cannot-open-file-libgfx-lib

Comment: @Samuel i posted there too but i was hoping someone here might be able to answer it.

Comment: I have seen that it is something from OpenGL, have you installed it? And are the links done right?

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon where am i mean to install OpenGL from?

Comment: @JamesTrotter Is it possible that http://mgarland.org/software/libgfx.html is a prerequisite for anarchy and you haven't obtained it? Can you find a libgfx.lib in the anarchy package somewhere or do you need to download and build it by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs is due to the default scaleform reference in the templates. 
from http://forum.projectanarchy.com/showthread.php?807-New-Release-2013-2-5 :

```
    The resulting project templates includes a reference to link against the Scaleform libraries. If you don't have or you don't need Scaleform in your project you will need to delete this references from the project. Because the project makes use of property sheets this libraries are linked automatically so if you don't need them you will have to: 

Right click in the ProjectTemplate→Properties.
Go to the Linker→General section.
Edit the Additional Dependencies field.
Uncheck the check-box labeled 'Inherit from parent or project defaults'.
Copy the contents of the 'Inherited values:' box (the one with light grey colour as background).
Paste the contents in the upper box under the already defined values.
Once pasted you must delete all the Scaleform entries:
-lgfx_air
-lgfx_as2
-lgfx_as3
-lgfx
-lgfxexpat
-lgfxplatform
-lgfxrender_gl
-lgfxsound_fmod
-lexpat
-ljpeg
-lpcre
-lpng
You will have to do this for each build configuration. This is Debug, Dev and Release.
```